# Getting: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Something went wrong while trying to open the window

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

This is my code in **service worker** for notification click event. Everything works fine, but I get this console error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Something went wrong while trying to open the window.` when I click the action button.

Why is this console error shown?

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', e => {
  const nf = e.notification;
  nf.close();
  if (!e.action) {
    if(nf.data && nf.data.url)
    {
      const url = nf.data.url;
      urltoopen(url,e);
    }
    return;
  }
  if(e.action === 'close'){
    return;
  }
  if(nf.data && nf.data.listurl)
  {
    const listurl = nf.data.listurl;
    Object.keys(listurl).forEach((k) => {
      if(k===e.action)
      {
        const actionurl=listurl[k];
        urltoopen(actionurl,e);
      }
    });
  }
});

function urltoopen(url,e) {
  const urlToOpen = new URL(url, self.location.origin).href;
  const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
    type: 'window',
    includeUncontrolled: true
  })
  .then((windowClients) => {
    let matchingClient = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
      const windowClient = windowClients[i];
      if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
        matchingClient = windowClient;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (matchingClient) {
      return matchingClient.focus();
    } else {
      return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
    }
  });
  e.waitUntil(promiseChain);
}
```

Comment: Check value of `urlToOpen` here `return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);`. Seems like it might be malformed.

Comment: Your for loop can be simplified: `const matchingClient = windowClients.find((wc) => wc.url === urlToOpen)`